# Total price incorrect after update the product's quantity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Now I am doing a cart list which I set the quantity=1 when the user add the product to cart, and when user open the cart it will show the total price of the products in the cart,In here user can increase/decrease the product's quantity in the cart and the total price will be update together. The problem that face by me now is when I increase or decrease the quantity of the product, the total price it show is incorrect

Below is the CartActivity code:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
            .setQuery(cartListRef.child("Cart")
                    .child(("Products")), Cart.class)
                    .build();

   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {

       @Override
       protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, final int i, @NonNull final Cart cart)
       {
           cartViewHolder.btn_quantity.setNumber(cart.getQuantity());
           cartViewHolder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price = RM"+cart.getPrice());
           cartViewHolder.txtProductName.setText(cart.getProductName());

           cartViewHolder.btn_quantity.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue)
               {
                 cart.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
                 cartListRef.child("Cart").child("Products").child(cart.getProductName()).child("quantity").setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));
                 getTotal();
               }

               private void getTotal()
               {
                   TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));
               }
           });
           TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));


}
```

---

Firebase real-time database:

```
{
"Cart List" : {
"Cart" : {
  "Products" : {
    "BenQ" : {
      "MemPrice" : "150",
      "Price" : "300",
      "ProductName" : "BenQ",
      "date" : "27 Dec 2019",
      "quantity" : "2",
      "time" : "00:37:56 a.m."
    },
    "Dell" : {
      "MemPrice" : "5000",
      "Price" : "10000",
      "ProductName" : "Dell",
      "date" : "26 Dec 2019",
      "quantity" : "4",
      "time" : "20:52:07 p.m."
    },
    "Logitech" : {
      "MemPrice" : "5",
      "Price" : "10",
      "ProductName" : "Logitech",
      "date" : "26 Dec 2019",
      "quantity" : "1",
      "time" : "20:42:58 p.m."
    }
  }
}
  },
"Product" : {
"Product1" : {
  "Barcode" : "112233",
  "MemPrice" : "5",
  "Price" : "10",
  "ProductName" : "Logitech"
},
"Product2" : {
  "Barcode" : "123456",
  "MemPrice" : "5000",
  "Price" : "10000",
  "ProductName" : "Dell"
},
"Product3" : {
  "Barcode" : "778899",
  "MemPrice" : "150",
  "Price" : "300",
  "ProductName" : "BenQ"
   }
 }
}
```

---

I use screenshot to state more clearly what I mean

**This is the image before I increase/decrease the quantity:**
[image: Before increase/decrease]

**This is the image I already increase/decrease the quantity:**
[image: After increase/decrease]

In the first picture it did not have any problem but in the second picture the total price should be RM 40610 but it show RM 112140

I hope that someone can help me to figure out what is the problem in my code or teach me how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the code causing the problem is here:

```
cartViewHolder.btn_quantity.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue)
   {
     cart.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
     cartListRef.child("Cart").child("Products").child(cart.getProductName()).child("quantity").setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));
     getTotal();
   }

   private void getTotal()
   {
       TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));
   }
});
TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));
```

Initially you're calculating the price of the item in this view holder and add that to the total: `TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));`.

But then every time the user changes the quantity, you again add the price for all items in this holder to the total.

So say that:

- The user starts with a 5 items that cost 20 each, you add 100 to the total.
- The user then adds one of that same item to the cart, ending up with 6. You add 6 * 20 = 120 to the total, while you should only be adding 20 for the one new item the user added.

The solution is to only add the difference in cost between `oldValue` and `newValue` items:

```
   public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue)
   {
     cart.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
     cartListRef.child("Cart").child("Products").child(cart.getProductName()).child("quantity").setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));

     TotalPrice = TotalPrice + (newValue - oldValue) * cart.getPrice();
   }
```

---

One unrelated recommendation: you're storing numeric values as strings in the database, which leads to a lot of type conversion in your code. If you instead store the numeric values as actual numbers, you can get rid of all the `Integer.valueOf(...)` and `String.valueOf(...)` calls and make your code a lot shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your help and recommendation, I had try the solution but the Total Price will become 0. Actually I set the quantity=1 when the user add the product to cart, and when user open the cart it will show the total price that the product in the cart, user also can increase/decrease the product's quantity in the cart and the total price will be update together

Comment: I had try the way below but I think this is not the perfect solution:
   
 `if(oldValue > newValue){
                           TotalPrice = TotalPrice - Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice());
                       }
                       else if(newValue > oldValue){
                           TotalPrice += (Integer.valueOf(cart.getPrice()));
                       }
                       count = false;
                   }`

Comment: is there any others solution?